# IOS - Store an object in Parse.com with REST API (POST)

Tags: ios, json, rest, parse-platform

I am trying to learn how to use Parse REST API and I have some problems with a POST request, to store new data. I am not using AFNetworking, but a class I normally use. I thought maybe this class had an error, but I did a GET request with no inconvenience.

I get this error:

> OUTPUT DATA: {
>       code = 107;
>       error = "invalid JSON";

**ViewController.m**

```
    NSMutableDictionary * dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dictionary setObject:@"Adriel" forKey:@"name"];
[dictionary setObject:@"tralala" forKey:@"icon"];
[dictionary setObject:@"He is bla bla bla bla bla " forKey:@"bio"];


[KPWebServiceController connectWithPOSTtoAPIURL:@"classes/User" withParams:dictionary andResponse:^(NSURLResponse *serviceResponse, id receivedData, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Response %@", receivedData);

}];
```

**Method:**

```
+ (void)connectWithPOSTtoAPIURL:(NSString *)APIURLString
                     withParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
                    andResponse:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *serviceResponse, id receivedData, NSError *error))responseHandler{

        NSError *error;


        NSString *venuesQuery = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error]
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Request %@", venuesQuery);

        NSMutableURLRequest *parseRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/?%@%@", ParseRestAPIURL, APIURLString, @"where=", venuesQuery]]];
        [parseRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [parseRequest setValue:ParseApplicationID forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
        [parseRequest setValue:ParseRestAPIID forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];

        NSLog(@"Request %@", parseRequest);

        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:parseRequest
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {


                                   id receivedData;
                                   if (connectionError) {
                                       NSLog(@"CONNECTION ERROR: %@", connectionError.localizedDescription);
                                   }

                                   else {
                                       NSError *jsonError;
                                       receivedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
                                       if (jsonError) {
                                           NSLog(@"JSON ERROR INPUT: %@",jsonError);
                                       }else {
                                           NSLog(@"OUTPUT DATA: %@", receivedData);
                                       }
                                   }

                                   responseHandler (response,receivedData,connectionError);
                               }];

}
```

I googled my problem and I checked it in SO, but this is how far I came to solve (not) it,

Comment: I know there is a Parse SDK for iOS. I was working with it before but now i am interested in learn how to work with REST API.

Comment: Additional info: Yeah I know te error is very self-explanatory. I double checked Json string in a Json Validator (That one, JsonLint). I don't know if maybe the problem is with encoding or something similar. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying some correction and the problem was not about the JSON String per se.

I modified my method, i deleted this encoding lines and it worked perfectly. (Yeah, I don't know what I did XD)

```
+ (void)connectWithPOSTtoAPIURL:(NSString *)APIURLString
                     withParams:(NSDictionary *)params
                  withKeyObject:(NSString *)keyObject
                    andResponse:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *serviceResponse, id receivedData, NSError *error))responseHandler{


    NSError *jsonError;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&jsonError];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", ParseRestAPIURL, APIURLString]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *dataRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [dataRequest setTimeoutInterval:30.0];
    [dataRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [dataRequest setValue:ParseApplicationID forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
    [dataRequest setValue:ParseRestAPIID forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
    [dataRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [dataRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:dataRequest
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

                               id receivedData;
                               if (connectionError) {
                               }

                               else {
                                   NSError *jsonError;
                                   receivedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
                                   if (jsonError) {
                                   }else {
                                       // NSLog(@"OUTPUT DATA: %@", receivedData);
                                   }
                               }

                               responseHandler (response,receivedData,connectionError);
                           }];

}
```

And i got this (awesome) response:

> Response {
>       createdAt = "2015-08-03T04:01:18.024Z";
>       objectId = sNqhMkX5yv; }

YAY! :)

I hope this would be helpful to others XD